# FindMinimum fails to find minimum even when it is given as the starting point

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Define:

```
sums[x_List] := Module[{n = Length[x]},
  Flatten[Table[x[[i]] + x[[j]], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}]]
]

score[x_List] := CentralMoment[Differences[Sort[sums[x]]]/(Max[x] - Min[x]), 2]

f[x_, y_] := score[{0, x, y, 1}]
```

Then, `f` looks like this:

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the *interior* of the domain shown, the surface has 4 minima (all nicely-behaved):

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 Contours -> Table[2^-i, {i, 3, 14}],
 MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I can't get any of the minimum-finding functions in *Mathematica* to find *any* of them.  For example:

```
In[25]:= NMinimize[{f[x, y], 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}]

Out[25]= {0.514286, {x -> 0.714287, y -> 1.}}

In[26]:= FindMinimum[{f[x, y], 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}]

Out[26]= {0.514286, {x -> 0.714285, y -> 1.}}
```

Even when I give *Mathematica* *one of the minima as starting point*, it *still* fails to find it:

```
In[27]:= f[1/4, 1/2]

Out[27]= 0

In[28]:= FindMinimum[{f[x, y], 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1}, {{x, 1/4}, {y, 1/2}}]

Out[28]= {0.514286, {x -> 0.714285, y -> 1.}}
```

(Note that `score` is non-negative, since it's a second central moment.  Therefore, any point `{x, y}` for which `f[x, y]` equals $0$ is a minimum.)

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Technically, that's "cheating". FindMinimum uses the slope to find the minimum point, so giving it a point with zero slope shouldn't work.

Comment: Specifying that the function only works for numbers helps: `f[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := ...`.

Comment: @wxffles: Brilliant!  That took care of it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In at least this case, one workaround avoiding `Sort[]` would be to use `RankedMin[]` instead, which is more amenable to symbolic processing, at the cost of being quite a bit slower to evaluate.

```
sums[x_?VectorQ] := Total[Subsets[x, {2}], {2}]

score[x_?VectorQ] := With[{s = sums[x]}, 
      CentralMoment[Differences[Table[RankedMin[s, k], {k, Length[s]}]],
                    2]/(Max[x] - Min[x])^2]

f[x_, y_] := score[{0, x, y, 1}]

Table[NMinimize[{f[x, y], 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}, 
                Method -> {"NelderMead", "RandomSeed" -> i}], {i, 5}] // Chop
   {{0, {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.75}}, {0, {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.25}}, {0, {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.25}},
    {0, {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.75}}, {0, {x -> 0.25, y -> 0.5}}}
```

Comment: @kjo, thanks for the acceptance, but I think wxffles's suggestion might be less expensive if your actual lists are long.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your expression for `score[{0, x, y, 1}]` seems to simplify considerably when $0<x,y<1$:

```
FullSimplify[score[{0, x, y, 1}], Thread[0 < {x, y} < 1]]
(* Out: 2/25 (7 x^2 - 2 x (2 + 3 y) + 2 (6 + (-2 + y) y)) *)

Minimize[Flatten@{%, Thread[0 < {x, y} < 1]}, {x, y}]
(* Out: {18/35, {x -> 5/7, y -> 1}} *)
```

The `Minimize` expression above also returns a warning:

> Minimize::wksol: Warning: there is no minimum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; returning a result on the boundary.

The symbolic result corresponds to the numerical one reported by `FindMinimum` and `NMinimize`.

Comment: I'm surprised that *Mathematica* can simplify the expression.  There's a `Sort` step in the expression for `score`, and I did not think that was amenable to analytic reduction.  Maybe therein lies the bug.

Comment: Afterthought: I think I did not get the point of your answer at first.  Now (especially after reading wxffles's comment) I see that it identifies the source of the problem.